# Capybara can not match xml page

Tags: cucumber, capybara, capybara-webkit

I have problem with matching response text on xml page on capybara.

When I use `page.should(have_content(arg1))` capybara raises error that there is no `\html` element (there shouldn't be as it's xml).

When I use `page.should(have_xpath(arg1))` it raises `Element at 40 no longer present in the DOM (Capybara::Webkit::NodeNotAttachedError)`

What is the correct way to test xml ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using capybara-webkit, the driver will try to use a browser's HTML DOM to look for elements. That doesn't work, because you don't have an HTML document.

One workaround is to fall back to Capybara's `string` implementation:

```
xml = Capybara.string(page.body)
expect(xml).to have_xpath(arg1)
expect(xml).to have_content(arg1)
```

Assuming your page returns a content type of `text/xml`, capybara-webkit won't mess with the response body at all, so you can pass it through to `Capybara.string` (or directly to Nokogiri if you like).